# Caffeine cache with custom expiry set dynamically never expires the cache and refreshes it

Tags: java, java-17, caffeine-cache

My spring config bean

```
@Bean
public Cache<String, Oauth2Token> Oauth2Cache(){
    return Caffeine.newBuilder()
            .initialCapacity(100)
            .maximumSize(1000)
            .expireAfter(new CustomExpiryOauth())
            .build();
}
```

Below is my customeExpiry implementation

```
public class CustomExpiryOauth implements CustomExpiry<String, Oauth2Token> {
    @Override
    public long expireAfterCreate(String key, Oauth2Token value, long currentTime) {
        log.info("expireAfterCreate value: {}", Long.parseLong(value.getExpiresIn())-2);
        return TimeUnit.SECONDS.toNanos(Long.parseLong(value.getExpiresIn())-2);
    }
    @Override
    public long expireAfterUpdate(String key, Oauth2Token value, long currentTime, long currentDuration) {
        return currentDuration;
    }
    @Override
    public long expireAfterRead(String key, Oauth2Token value, long currentTime, long currentDuration) {
        return currentDuration;
    }
}
```

Below is defined in my service class.
I will get expiry time when getOauth2Token() is invoked which I put in the cache. Defined Lambda function thinking that it will helps refresh the cache when it is expired.

```
@Cacheable(cacheNames = "oauth2Cache" ,key = "#myMap.get('systemName')")
public Oauth2Token getOauth2TokenFromCache(Map<String, String> myMap) {
    log.info("At getOauth2TokenFromCache expiresIn = {} ",getOauth2Token(myMap).getExpiresIn());
    return oauth2Cache.get(myMap.get("systemName"), k -> getOauth2Token(myMap));
}
```

When the cache entry expires, does that mean the oauth2Cache.get(keyString) will return null and CustomExpiryOauth.expireAfter() will be called to refresh the cache. This is not happening when cache entry expires, also I get below error when customeExpiry is invoked on adding new entry.
What is wrong here? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: **ERROR**: 
java.lang.NumberFormatException: Cannot parse null string
 at java.base/java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:674)
CustomExpiryForOauth.expireAfterCreate(CustomExpiryForOauth.java:15)

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know Spring, but it looks like you are using it AND calling caffeine directly, so perhaps double caching? The NPE in your comment indicates that Oauth2Token's getExpiresIn() method returns a null value so it fails to parse. When the entry expires the cache will call your `mappingFunction` to load it anew so a new value is obtained. However if you have double caching then Spring `@Cacheable` might have no eviction set, so it never calls the method again. You should probably use only one mode, either Caffeine's api directly or implicitly through Spring Cache.

Comment: Thanks @BenManes. As you said I was double caching that was causing the issue. I'm not aware how to configure Cache with customExpiry via spring. So I went ahead with non-spring approach and it worked. I need not even schedule to evict the expired cache entries. It is automatically taken care.